# Repeat the task of an awk file for different variable

Tags: linux, awk

So I have a text file like this:

```
1.0 56
2.0 48
1.0 78
1.0 12
3.0 68
```

the 1.0, 2.0 are all user id and i have up till 43.0. so i wrote an awk script to process the file:

```
BEGIN {
    total = 0
}
{
    length = $2
}
{
    if ($1 == "1.0") {
    total += length
    }
}
END {
    printf("%.2f\n",total)
}
```

so basically it takes the sum of the lengths of user 1.0 and sums it all. I have to do that to the other users as well. What changes should i do in the script so that it processes the text file completely for user 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, etc and gives the totals for each user as output (without having to change the `awk` file everytime i have to compute for a user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in `awk`

```
awk '{unique[$1]+=$2}END{for (i in unique) print i,unique[i]}' input-file
```

The idea is the above creates a hash-map, with `$1` being the unique entry in the array which has your values from `1.0`, `2.0` etc. We are adding the value of length which is `$2` in the file. Since the array is indexed by `$1`, the command updates the sum for every unique user in the file. The `END` clause is executed after all the lines are processed which basically prints out the user id with the sum calculated.